# Unable to filter data with timestamp value using Mybatis and Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, mybatis, sql-timestamp

I have a `student_audit` table where I am storing some audit information for the student.

The table has existing data.

```
ID | NAME | AUDIT_TIMESTAMP
___________________________
1  | TEST | 22-JUN-22 07.23.59.515462000 AM
```

The DDL for the table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE student_audit (
  id NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  audit_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_stdnt_aud PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I have a mapper method in `StudentDao.java`

```
StudentEntity getStudent(@Param("name") String name,
      @Param("auditTimestamp") Timestamp auditTimestamp)
```

```
public class StudentEntity {
  
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  // java.sql.Timestamp
  private Timestamp auditTimestamp;

  // getters and setters

}
```

The `StudentDao.xml` method is as follows

```
<resultMap id="studentMap"
               type="fully-qualified-name-of-StudentEntity ">
    <result property="id" column="id"/>
    <result property="name" column="name"/>
    <result property="auditTimestamp" column="auditTimestamp"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getStudent"
    resultMap="studentMap">
    SELECT
      s.id
    , s.name
    , s.audit_timestamp as auditTimestamp
    FROM
      student_audit s
    WHERE
      s.audit_timestamp = #{auditTimestamp}
</select>
```

When I run an integration test against this Dao method, its always returning null. However, the following query in SQL developer is returning the value.

```
select * from student_audit 
where audit_timestamp = TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-06-22 07:23:59.515462', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF');
```

I tried the following solutions:

1. Using the `SqlTimestampTypeHandler` along with the audit timestamp value
2. Using `jdbcType` attribute

I have not been able to resolve this.

Adding logs from the console

```
11:44:46.495 [main] DEBUG c.c.w.f.e.p.r.StudentDao.getStudent - ==>  Preparing: SELECT s.id, s.name, s.audit_timestamp as auditTimestamp FROM student_audit s WHERE s.audit_timestamp = ?
11:44:46.551 [main] DEBUG c.c.w.f.e.p.r.StudentDao.getStudent - ==> Parameters: 2022-06-22 07:23:59.515462(Timestamp)
11:44:47.240 [main] DEBUG c.c.w.f.e.p.r.StudentDao.getStudent - <==      Total: 0
```

Comment: Please enable TRACE level logging and add the output to the question. The log contains the statement and parameter values.

Comment: I have attached the logs from the console.

Comment: It works fine for me. Try this executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-74697714).